# RegEx to split and extract based strict requirement

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I’m using Nintex Workflows with a RegEx action. I believe the RegEx is based on .NET. I need to perform a RegEx on some data that is sent to me by users who input it in a different formats based on the person writing the data.

```
Test: A-BC12 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
Test: A-DE34 (1,2,3,4, words, 5,6,7,8,9);
Test: AFG56 (1,2,3,4 word, 5);
STOP some extra
```

My goal is this.

```
Start the extract after Test:
Capture the last 4 of the alpha numeric before the parenthesis
Capture the numbers only inside the parenthesis    
Split each data based on ;
End the whole capture when the word STOP is found.
```

End results

```
BC12 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
DE34 (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
FG56 (1,2,3,4,5);
```

I have tried splitting the data, forward lookup and exclude and I can’t seem to get everything to work together. If I have to execute multiple RegEx to achieve my results I’m ok with that.

I’ve tried the following to achieve each one of my goals
`(?s)(?<=^.*?Test:\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+` this only capture the first ABC12 or A-BC12 then stops
`[,;]`  split the data so it is easier to maintain. However the word Test: is captured.

I feel I'm going in the right direction, however I'm missing something or taking the wrong approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to omit the first group you can use this regex: `Test:\s*A[^;]*;(.*?)STOP`.

That way, you can take `$1` and split it on `;`.

---

Edit: Clarifications have rendered the above solution obsolete. I've made new stuff that will directly address your steps:

```
 a. Start the extract after Test:
 b. Capture the last 4 of the alpha numeric before the parenthesis
 c. Capture the numbers only inside the parenthesis    
 d. Split each data based on ;
 e. End the whole capture when the word STOP is found.
```

You're actually looking for something like:

1. Use `Test:\s*(.*?)STOP`. This addresses steps `a` and `e`.
2. Take `$1` and use `[A-Z0-9]{4}\s*\(([^)]*)\);`. This addresses steps `b` and `d`.
3. Take the `$1` from the previous step, and use `([0-9]+)` to get the numbers. This will get all the numbers, and if given: `9,10` it will produce two matches: `9` and `10`.

You may need to use modifiers, like `i` for case insensitive, `s` for single line, and `g` for global.

I hope this is finally what you're looking for!

Comment: This is not working for me. The capture skips the `Test:` and the first entry and then captures everything from that point forward even the words that are contained within the parenthesis. The options I have for the RegEx are `Replace Text`, `Split` and `Extract`. The only option that I have to insert the `$1` is the `Replace Text` option.

Comment: @JeremyA1 Please specify what you want. Nowhere did you say anything about not wanting the parenthesis' content.

Comment: I've updated my original post to reflect what I'm trying to achieve. My apologies for omitting the part about the parenthesis

Comment: Laurel I changed the capture to the following to create a non capture group `(?<=Test:\s)(?:(?!STOP).)*` The problem I'm having is that step 2 is removing the last 4 alpha numeric not extracting them.

Comment: My apologies since I can't edit my original post everything is working as expected. Thank you so much